# Dashboard com php

Tags: php

Estou montando uma pagina de gerenciamento e gostaria de acrescentar nela alguns Dashboard's dinâmicos com o sistema da loja através do PHP, mas já procurei e não acho ninguém explicando como fazer isso. Eu gostaria de algum tipo pra ver quantas pessoas estiveram no site ou algo assim sabe ? sendo representado por um gráfico de pizza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe uma formula pronta amigo, imagina que a dashboard, mas basicamente você vai criar vários scipts no seu site que coletam informações e guarda esses dados no banco de dados. Depois na sua dashboard o trabalho seria só mostrar essas informações coletadas;

Um exemplo seria você ter uma tabela com o nome da pagina e o numero de  os acessos, quando alguém acessar uma pagina você adiciona 1 a o registro do banco daquela pagina.

No dashboard você apenas lê no banco cata pagina e os seus acessos e mostra na tela.

Esse é um exemplo simples é que pode ser muito melhorado, mas você pode começar por isso. minha dica é procurar pessoas que já tentaram fazer( Scripts), melhorar eles e usar a criatividade ao máximo.